# Drupal language does not change after "Choose language" installation step

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, debian

I'm setting up a Drupal installation from the zip downloaded from drupalfr.org. I choose French, but after the Language Choosing step, the installation assistant stays in English.
I also tried to download the last Drupal 7 distribution, from the official Drupal website and to install the French language from drush, but even if the French language is enable and set by default, the whole Drupal installation (site and admin) stays in English.
I think in can come from the php settings, but I don't see anything wrong. I'm developing on a Vagrant machine working on Debian, and everything about the webserver is up to date.

Do you have an idea of where this problem can come from ?

Comment: Did you try through the i18n module too?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at /admin/config/regional/translate/update to see if the you have the necessary translation files. If you don't have this menu option, try enabling the core module 'locale' and installing and enabling [l10n update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update).